# Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK version warning during app publishing

Tags: android, sdk, google-mobile-ads

I am encountering a warning regarding the 'Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK' when trying to publish my app. The warning mentions that I am using version 15.0.0, but I have been unable to locate this version in any of my files(can not even find the SDK).

Furthermore, the Google Play Console recently informed me that I need to upgrade the SDK in order to publish new versions of my app.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to address this warning and avoid potential issues during the publishing process.